# Specify which dependency to use in ctor injection with CastleWindsor 2.5.1.0

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I have a class with constructor like this

```
public class BlotterService : IBlotterService
{
    public BlotterService(IAService aService, IAnotherService anotherService)
    {
        // ...  
    } 
}
```

and registered dependencies like this

```
// Default lifecycle is Singleton
Component.For<IAnotherService >().ImplementedBy<AnotherService >()
Component.For<IAService>().ImplementedBy<AService>() // instance 1 of AService
Component.For<IAService>().ImplementedBy<AService>().Named(
                    "aServiceAlternativeForBlotter") // instance 2 of AService
Component.For<IBlotterService>().ImplementedBy<BlotterService>()
```

Typically when classes requiring IAService are instantiated I want the first instance of AService, however in the specific case of BlotterService, I want instance 2 of AService.

How can I register BlotterService/AService with the castle container to achieve this?

**EDIT: Update**

I am using Castle 2.5.1.0 and sadly cannot upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of right answers in here, but you're stuck on 2.5, so I think what you'll need to do is something like this:

```
Component.For<IBlotterService>()
    .ImplementedBy<BlotterService>()
    .ServiceOverrides(
        ServiceOverride.ForKey("aService").Eq("aServiceAlternativeForBlotter"));
```

If this doesn't work, then another alternative is you could create an interface derived from IService named IAlternateService, and then have a dependency on that...

Comment: Spot on Jonnii - works perfectly for 2.5.1. ForKey("ctorParameterName").Eq("useThisNamedImplementation")

Comment: I felt obliged to help considering I'm the reason you're using windsor in the first place ;)

Comment: LOL. No hard feelings ;) I just remembered doing something like this in Unity and didn't want to create yet another factory class to circumvent it

Comment: Windsor has a factory facility, so you don't need to create lots of factories, just a factory interface, it'll fill in the blanks.

Comment: someone on our team just went "Ok that's great, but if someone changes the ctor parameter name aService it won't work". Good point. We'll need the type safe version provided by 3.0.0 as per Mark Seemanns answer, but still thanks : )

Comment: Mark Seemann's answer isn't type safe, it's just less noise, the same code as I've posted gets created under the hood, it's just done with an anonymous type and some reflection. What you'll need to is write a unit test to check the constructor parameter is there.

Comment: doing that right now as it happens. However beginning to think the factory idea wasn't such a bad one after all

Answer (score 8):

Change the last registration to:

```
Component
    .For<IBlotterService>()
    .ImplementedBy<BlotterService>()
    .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent(
        typeof(IAService),
        "aServiceAlternativeForBlotter"))
```

Comment: Just tried this, Dependency.OnComponent is not found - what version of Castle are you using?

Comment: Latest version from NuGet: 3.0.0.4001

Comment: :-( Sadly Im on 2.5.1 - legacy enterprise app. I will google the equivalent in 2.5

Comment: Nope, as that doesn't compile either as posted in comments

Answer (score 1):

During the registration of BlotterService you need to specify its dependency with an override.

```
Component.For<IBlotterService>().ImplementedBy<BlotterService>().ServiceOverrides(
                new { aService = "aServiceAlternativeForBlotter" })
```

Or you could use one of the DependsOn overrides.

Comment: Also tried this - doesn't compile. These are both in the right ball park but so far unable to get a solution - I'm still playing with both permutations though